# Using a list to store discount codes, and removing them from the list once they are redeemed

Tags: python

I am storing discount codes with different prefixes and unique digits at the end (`10OFF<abc>`, `25OFF<abc>`, `50OFF<abc>`, etc.) in a file, and then loading that file into a list.

I am trying to make a function so that when they are redeemed, they are removed from the list, and the file is overwritten. Right now what I am doing looks like this:

```
for x in range(0, 5):
    total += codes[0] + '\n'
    codes.remove(codes[0])
with open('codes.txt', 'w') as f:
    for code in codes:
        f.write(code+'\n')
```

For one thing, I don't think this is a very pythonic way of doing things, and it feels dirty. And for another, theres not really a way for me to specify which discount code to select and remove - doing it this way i would have to make separate files for the `10OFF`, `25OFF`, and `50OFF` codes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The suggestion is to use sqlite3 instead of a normal text file.

Comment: Using a tuple and use the method `.pop(index)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you want

```
list_of_codes=open('codes.txt','rt').read().split('\n')

while True:
    code=input('enter code to remove:')
    if code in list_of_codes:
       break
    else:
       print('code you entered is not in the list')
       continue

list_of_codes.pop(list_of_codes.index(code))

with open('codes.txt','wt') as f:
    [f.write(item+'\n') for item in list_of_codes]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code promps the user to input all the code he whishes to remove, then it reads the current file and overwrites the file with only the code that were NOT input by the user. The file considers the whole content of a line as a code (must contain prefix + unique digits).

The code also leaves the old file as a backup, so you can inspect the changes afterwards.

```
import datetime
import shutil

def remove(base_file_name, codes_to_remove):
    now_ = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_file_name = '{}.txt'.format(base_file_name)
    backup_file_name = '{}-{}.txt'.format(base_file_name, now_.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'))

    # copy current file to the new name, which will also be kept as backup
    shutil.copy2(current_file_name, backup_file_name)

    with open(backup_file_name, 'r') as fr, open(current_file_name, 'w') as fw:
        for line in fr:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                # 'line' will be an individual code
                if line not in codes_to_remove:
                    fw.write('{}\n'.format(line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_list = input('Enter codes to remove (separated by spaces): ').split()
    remove('my-codes', code_list)
```

Suppose the file **my-codes.txt** contains the following lines:

```
25OFF123456
25OFF123457
25OFF123458
50OFF111112
50OFF111113
```

When you run this code, and when prompted you input a few codes:

```
Enter codes to remove (separated by spaces): 50OFF111112 50OFF111114
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then afterwards the file **my-codes.txt** will contain one less code (the second code from the prompt `50OFF111114` does not exist in the file and will have no effect):

```
25OFF123456
25OFF123457
25OFF123458
50OFF111113
```

You also will be left with a new file called **my-codes-20181101-120102.txt** which will contain the original 5 codes from before running the script.

---

Notes:

- if you have thousands of codes and are looking for more speed, then you should look into using databases. But for only a few hunderd codes this should sufice.
- Your promo codes can be of any format, as long as the file contains a single code per line, and you have to input the code into the prompt exactly like it is in the file. Of course, you can modify this script to fit your specific use case.

Comment: Sorry, i don’t think i was clear enough. i don’t want them to have to be manually deleted. The codes are sent when someone uses a discord command. I want the codes in the list to be deleted after they are sent so that the bot does not send a duplicate code to a user.

Comment: Well, in that case your bot simply could invoke the function `remove()` that I suggested, passing the promo codes as parameter.

Comment: @jkorn95 But if there is a chance that there will be any kind of concurrency (multiple simultaneos calls to your bot), then you should consider using a proper database that can handle that, because a simple text file is not meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a database structure for this such as maybe [TinyDB](https://pypi.org/project/tinydb/) *(uses json in the background)*. Or at the very least making the file a .json file and using [dataIO](https://pypi.org/project/dataIO/). This way saving and loading are faster and you keep a `list` in python that's easy to use.

Also python has a built in unique generator called [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) that I use for unique strings.

```
from uuid import uuid4 as gen
import dataIO

filepath = '~/codes.json'
codes = ('10OFF<{}>', '25OFF<{}>', '50OFF<{}>', etc.)

#initial setup
if not dataIO.is_valid_json(filepath):
    all_codes = {'codes':[]}
    save_codes()
#load the database
db = dataIO.load_json(filepath)
all_codes = db['codes']

def get_codes():
    generated_codes = [c.format(gen.hex[:8]) for c in codes]
    #Display the codes generated
    print('\n'.join(generated_codes))
    #Save them to file
    all_codes.append(generated_codes)
    save_codes()

def use_code(code):
    if code in all_codes:
        all_codes.pop(code)
        print("Enjoy {}% Off!".format(code[2:]))
    else:
        print("Invalid code!")

#just for ease of typing out the following
def save_codes()
    dataIO.save_json(filename, all_codes)
```

This has the basics on saving/loading and using just a .json file as your mini database. You could even just use python's `csv` library to save and load as a .csv and load it back as a list if this is the only detail you're saving to file *(idk why)*. I'd do some research and find what works best for you!

**Edit**
Just to inform you, `db` isn't an actual database, it's just a .json file which is basically a dict and it's saved to disk. `codes` is just a key in `db` whish holds a list of all the codes. With this approach, you can also have a users list of dicts in `db` and more. You may want to associate codes to certain users and such, this and more are much easier if you use a database format. This is just a quick and dirty, but imo efficient way of accomplishing this as your question is only asking about storing codes. Good luck!